# Programmatically get list of base packages

Tags: r

How can I get R to list its base install packages.  Dirk gives a list [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9705725/1000343) but how can I get R to tell me this information, that is the packages in `src/library/`?

`getOption("defaultPackages")` is close but only lists some of these packages.

Comment: `getOption("defaultPackages")` is actually exactly what I was looking for, thanks! It's just the packages that R loads on startup.

Comment: Be careful as `c(getOption("defaultPackages"), "base")` is what R loads on startup. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
rownames(installed.packages(priority="base"))
 [1] "base"      "compiler"  "datasets"  "graphics"  "grDevices" "grid"     
 [7] "methods"   "parallel"  "splines"   "stats"     "stats4"    "tcltk"    
[13] "tools"     "utils"
```

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR.

- `rownames(installed.packages(priority = "base"))` all base packages for your `R.Version()`.
- `c(getOption("defaultPackages"), "base")` is what R loads on startup

`installed.packages` will return your currently installed packages.
Where base packages are always the same per certain R version (`R.Version()`). It is possible that this list will change in the future with a newer R version. E.g. As i remember `parallel` was added later than others [R `parallel` package does not exist on CRAN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603098/r-parallel-package-does-not-exist-on-cran).

`getOption("defaultPackages")` is what R loads on startup although the `base` package is not counted.
I find out that `sessionInfo()$basePkgs` solution is more robust for startup packages as it contains a `base` package too. However `sessionInfo()$basePkgs` is relatively highly inefficient because it is a simple loop across all DESCRIPTION files.

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sessionInfo()$basePkgs,
                               getOption("defaultPackages"))
Unit: nanoseconds
                         expr     min      lq       mean  median      uq      max neval
       sessionInfo()$basePkgs 6172017 6242209 6673759.42 6294546 6848292 16656578   100
 getOption("defaultPackages")     205     246     526.85     451     656     1722   100
```

Answer (score 2):

There might be a simpler method, but I think that this should do the trick:

```
installed.packages()[grep('^base$', installed.packages()[, 'Priority']), ]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I like @Josh's just a little more for simplicity +1

Comment: Of course - I didn't look at the args to `installed.packages`, and @Josh's is much clearer.