# In Google Colab, How to Import Package Like car, mtcars Using importr?

Tags: python, r, google-colaboratory, rpy2

**What Was I Trying to Do?**

I was trying to calculate VIF (Variance Inflation Factor) using `VIF` function of `car` package of R. In python, to import the car package, I used the `importr` function of `rpy2` as shown below.

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
car = importr('car')
```

**Then, What Did Happen?**

However, after running the codes in Google Colab, I got the following error.

```
PackageNotInstalledError: The R package "car" is not installed.
```

I understand that it is saying that the package `car` is not installed.

**Then, My Question**

In Google Colab, I did not need to install any package like Keras, Pandas etc.. In fact, I did not need to install `stats` package (to use via `rpy2`) of R. Then, why will I need to install package like `car`, `usdm`, `mtcars` to use via `rpy2`? Also, I do not know how to install those packages to use through the `rpy2` library.

**How Did I Try to Solve?**

I searched on Google to find the ways to use (via `rpy2`) those packages (e.g. `car`, `mtcars`) in Google Colab. However, I failed to find the ways. It can be noted that I can use those packages (e.g. `usdm`, `car`) via `rpy2` in Jupyterlab Notebook (after installing). However, I want to use those packages in Google Colab.

*Any type of help will be greatly appreciated!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why?** Because R can be installed with or without extra packages. Apparently Google Colab contains a minimal installation of R, including only the built-in R packages such as `base`, `utils`, `stats` etc. To re-iterate, these packages are a part of R by default (not on CRAN). Any other packages that you get when installing R are bonus for your convenience; for example in Ubuntu you have `r-base` and `r-recommended`; typically one would get both, but system admins who are short on space might decide to only provide the former. See [Difference between r-base and r-recommended packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700799/difference-between-r-base-and-r-recommended-packages)

**How?** You need to install it with:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

utils = importr('utils')
utils.install_packages('car')
```

Comment: In addition the example in the answer, the doc covers the topic of installing R packages: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.4.x/html/introduction.html#installing-packages

Comment: Can you please let me know how to save these installed packages to google drive permanently? In SO, though some answers (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253498/how-do-i-install-a-library-permanently-in-colab)) already available regarding pip installed packages, however I do not find any answer regarding packages installed via `install_packages()` function.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution by `devtools`(R package) for GitHub repos,

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

utils = importr('utils')
utils.install_packages('devtools')
devtools = rpackages.importr('devtools')
devtools.install_github("xxx/xxx")
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is one year old, but I have had the same issue just now and I have figured out a way to install `car` in a Colab notebook:

A big problem is that R is not very forthcoming with its error messages in a Colab notebook. The issue for me was two offending dependencies, namely the `nloptr`-package and the `gsl`-package, that I had to find through extensive trial and error.

In the end, I had to manually install `nloptr` version 1.0.4 as well as `gsl` version 1.2-19 from source. This means you have to download both archives from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/, copy them to your Google Drive and then install.

I should point out that I am using Python and R simultaneously via cell magic and `rpy2.ipython`. So in this case, I have to preface every notebook cell that uses R-code with `%%R`.

Also be mindful that you have to mount your Google Drive to Colab beforehand (in a regular Python cell) to be able to install the R-package from source. Put the two together and you get:

```
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
from google.colab import files, drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Then you can install `nlopre` and `gsl` from source and, finally, `car` from CRAN:

```
%%R
install.packages("drive/MyDrive/nloptr_1.0.4.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
install.packages("drive/MyDrive/src/gsl_1.2-19.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")
install.packages("car", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org")
```

Comment: I adapted the answer slightly: The correct `loptr`-version is 1.0.4. You also need to install `gsl` version 1.2-19 from source before installing `car`.

Answer (score -1):

do pip install with following code in colab.

!pip install packageName

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I tried it before posting the question here. But it did not work.