# Are there any Base functions that lets you compute the md5/hash of a file?

Tags: r

I try stick to Base R as much as I can due to my experience with workplaces blocking installation of packages in the past.

If there truly are no good functions in Base R then I will look into packages, but I just want to make sure I am not missing anything.

Comment: You should be able to use `tools::md5sum`. That comes with R by default. It's one of the base packages: `names(which(installed.packages()[ ,"Priority"] == "base", ))`

Comment: More info on the packages included in "Base R": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700799/difference-between-r-base-and-r-recommended-packages

Comment: Alternatively, this should be pretty easy to code up on your own.  Makes a fun small project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `tools` package is a "base" package and is automatically included with R. So you can use `tools::md5sum` to calculate the MD5 sum without further dependencies.